# Use carrierwave with Bearer token Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, bearer-token

I am currently using carrierwave to upload a photo using the `remote_url` method.

Today I have access to a link secured with a `Bearer Authorization` token. Unfortunately our image provider does not allow us to access the image via the `?access_token=VALID_TOKEN` protocol.

Is it possible to configure carrierwave to pass `Bearer VALID_TOKEN` in the `Authorization` header ? Or other ideas to fix my issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create file `config/initializers/bearer.rb` with following code:

```
module CarrierWave
  module Uploader
    module Download
      class RemoteFile
        def file
          if @file.blank?
            @file = Kernel.open(@uri.to_s, 'Authorization' => 'Bearer VALID TOKEN')
            @file = @file.is_a?(String) ? StringIO.new(@file) : @file
          end
          @file

        rescue Exception => e
          raise CarrierWave::DownloadError, "could not download file: #{e.message}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now your token will be sent for each `remote_url`.